# Hacer responsive este diseño sin duplicar elementos

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive, flexbox

Tengo que maquetar un slider según este diseño para escritorio y tablet:

Escritorio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0jBT.jpg

Tablet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47EFs.jpg

-El icono de la imagen es donde las imágenes del slider van a ir apareciendo.

-Otro de los bloques magentas tiene los controles del slider.

-El último bloque magenta tiene algún texto sin importancia.

Hay dos background-images en esas texturas feas que puse.

He comenzado con la versión escritorio usando flexbox, **pero cuando intento ajustar el responsive para el diseño tablet me encuentro que es imposible porque estos dos elementos están en rows diferentes.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1haX.jpg

Este es mi código actual más o menos:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img class="logo-img"
                     src="assets/images/logo.png">
                <div class="titulo-boton">
                    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
                <div class="row primera" primera>
                    <div class="col yourtrip">
                        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
                        <hr>
                        <p class="tags">#tags</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>

                    <div class="col ">
                        <div class="image-slider image-wrap">
                            <!--                            <img src="assets/images/rocket.png">-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" segunda>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col controls" controls>
                        <div class="botones row w-100">
                            <div class="col p-0">
                                <a href="#" class="btn">prev</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col p-0">
                                <a href="#" class="btn">next</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**¿Alguna idea de como organizar el html o las columnas para no tener ese problema?**

Gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: Dado a que estas intentando manejar un diseño que debe organizarse tomando en cuenta 2 dimensiones, creo que sugereriria intentar crear la estructura con CSS Grid; Bootstrap es Flexbox puro, por lo que se enfoca en una sola dimension... Aunque es posible, es trabajo mucho mas complejo hacerlo con Flexbox

Comment: @IvanS95 Hola Ivan, gracias por tu aporte. Pensé en usar CSS Grid pero en la empresa en la que trabajaba hasta hace unos días lo tenían prohibido porque decían que no tenía soporte por algunos navegadores de Microsoft. 
https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20grid
Por lo que veo en los Edge si que está soportado así que tienes razon que igual es mejor tirar por ahí. Probaré entonces.

Comment: Añade más detalles, como tu CSS